# Disallow app access when app update in progress

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Is it possible to disallow user to access the app when the update is in progress?

In my app there is a scenario where in user are forced to update the app by tapping on the external link and download from ipa. While the update is in progress But if the app is in background the user can still access the app.

Is there any workaround to prevent user to access the app when the app update is in progress?

If not Is there any documentation provided by Apple to show that it is the default behaviour of iOS?

Comment: Updating the app from the App Store, ie a new version of the app?  Or updating content?

Comment: new version of the app.. through ipa from enterprise account and not through app store

Comment: Don't app icons already gray out and get a progress icon on them when an update is happening?

Comment: Yes they do, But if the app is in background, you can still open it by double tapping the home button

Answer (score 0):

While updating an app, your app's icon will get greyed out and user will not be able to open the app. Its default behaviour so won't have to manage it externally

Comment: Yes, thats the default behavior, I agree, but when the app is in background, you can still access the app